# FakeData "Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field"

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I made my first apollo server to try to understand it and so far I'm testing it with an array I created and I test my mutation with graphQL playground.

My data is a big array Like this:

```
const lists = [
    {
      id: 'list-0',
      name: 'Example 1',
      tasks: [{name:"task1", id:"1", completed: false},{name:"task2", id:"2", completed: true}, ]
      },
    {
      id: 'list-1',
      name: 'Example 2',
      tasks: [{name:"task1", id:"1", completed: false},{name:"task2", id:"2", completed: true}, ]
    },
  ];
```

So far I'm able to add a list name, delete a list and get a list by id. What I would like to do is, add a new task object to a list.

My mutation and type are like this:

```
type Task {
  id: String!
  name: String!
  completed: Boolean!
}

type List {
  id: String!
  name: String!
  tasks: [Task!]!
}

addTask(listId: String!, name: String!): Task!
```

The function addTask I made for my resolvers is this:

```
        addTask(parents, {listId, name}) {
            const newTask = lists.map((list) => {
              if (listId === list.id) {
                return {
                  ...list,
                tasks: [...list.tasks, { name, completed: false, id:"eaz"}],
              };
            }
            console.log("test1", list)
            return list
            })
            console.log("test2", newTask)
            return newTask
          },
```

When I use the graphQL playground I target one of my list.id like this one below but the console log tell me tasks: [ [Object], [Object] ] and the graphQL playground bring tell me tasks is null.

```
mutation Mutation {
  addTask(listId: "task-0", name: "eze") {
    name
  }
}
```

Am I missing something about graphQL?Should I seperate the array tasks and lists?
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your console logs, `newTask` looks like this:

```js
[ [Object], [Object] ]
```

It's an array, not an object, and `[].name` is `undefined`, which gets converted to `null`.

Based on your type definitions, you must return an object that has this structure:

```
type Task {
  id: String!
  name: String!
  completed: Boolean!
}
```

If instead, your code did something like this, I think it'll give you want you're saying it's returning:

```js
  addTask(parents, { listId, name }) {
    let newTask
    lists.forEach((list) => {
      if (listId === list.id) {
        newTask = { name, completed: false, id: 'eaz' }
        list.tasks.push(newTask)
      }
      console.log('test1', list)
      return list
    })
    console.log('test2', newTask)
    return newTask
  }
```

newTask here is the object `{ name, completed: false, id: 'eaz' }`

---

#### Extra credit:

Alternative to .map or .forEach, which loops through EVERY ITEM NO MATTER WHAT, you can do something a bit more efficient like

```js
  addTask(parents, { listId, name }) {
    const newTask = { name, completed: false, id: 'eaz' }
    const list = lists.find((list) => {
      return listId === list.id
    }
    if (!list) throw new Error('listId not found')
    list.tasks.push(newTask)
    console.log('test1', list)
    console.log('test2', newTask)
    return newTask
  }
```